# About list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

In one expression I want to count the amount of vowels in L. I know this can be done with a list comprehension but I am having trouble thinking of the solution. Especially because you can't use ors with strings.

```
L = "thanks yoU For the help"
```

list comprehension

```
L = [Not sure for L in L.lower().split() if not sure]

print L
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1,]
```

I want it to print the number of vowels in each word. I know I have to use split and I would like to lower case it to make it easier as well. I am not sure if I am going at this right or not.

Comment: Yes, you're going at it right - you've split the sentence into words. Now how do you count the vowels in each word?

Comment: L = [L.count('a') for L in L.lower().split() if 'a' in L] this is what I have so far I am not entirely sure how to do the rest though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
L = "thanks yoU For the help".lower()
L2 = [sum(x.count(y) for y in 'aeoiu') for x in L.split()]
print (L2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Explanation:**
`L.split()` creates a `list` where all the elements are lower case because of the `.lower()`:

```
['thanks', 'you', 'for', 'the', 'help']
```

`for x in L.split()` iterates through each word in that list and `for y in 'aeoiu'` iterates through each character in the string `'aeoiu'`. Then,`sum(x.count(y)` counts how many times `y` *winch is any of the characters in `'aeoiu'`* is in `x` *which is each word in `['thanks', 'you', 'for', 'the', 'help']`*

Comment: I just tried that bit of code it didn't seem to work I would also like the .lower() figured into the one expression if possible? Thank you though. I think I could figure it out if I understood the list comprehension but I haven't been able to find a good place that explains it well.

Comment: hey thank you I really appreciate that clears things up a bit the code did work and I actually moved the .lower() down to the L.split() and got it to work there as well so perfect thanks again!

Comment: @gummybear Great! You should click the answer as the right answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: sorry I was trying it didn't let me earlier. I am new to the site, at least in the form of participating lol.

Comment: @gummybear Great! Thanks. Welcome to SO.